# SAMP download links or Setups?

Tags: solaris

**Do we have any link for SAMP** (Solaris,Apache,MySQL,PHP/Perl) ?. Couldnt find in google. Appreciate the responses

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.oracle.com/solaris and click the "Download" link.

Once you've installed Solaris, you can use "pkg install" to install Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl, Python, etc. from the Solaris pkg repo, as described in Chapter 1 of the guide [Setting Up the Application Development Environment in Oracle Solaris 11](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=solaris11&id=OSADE).